# Walking a filesystem with java recursive depth-first

Tags: java, recursion, filesystems

i need to walk through a random filesystem(windows) with java.

The catch: it needs to walk bottom up cause i merge data together and the root should contain all of my data-sets.

That's what i have so far:

```
private void listDir(File dir) {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
            if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                System.out.print(" (Directory)\n");
                listDir(files[i]);  //Recursion
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(" (File)\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So any ideas how to realize that?

I appreciate any help and hope i don't annoy you with my questions ^^

Comment: You should be able to use a [`FileVisitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor)). Do your merge in the [`postVisitDirectory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html#postVisitDirectory(T,%20java.io.IOException)) method.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what "walking bottom-up" means to you. Are you looking at a a reverse depth-first merge, or breadth-first? Give an example on a tree..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, with depth-first tree recursion, you can influence the order of your output by changing the order of your output statements and recursive calls.

Take this tree:

```
        1
       / \
      2   3
     / \   \
    4   5   6
```

If my code says (all the code in this answer is pseudocode):

```
 void f(Node node) {
      if(node == null) return;
      print node.value;
      f(node.left);
      f(node.right);
 }
```

... then it will output `1 2 4 5 3 6` -- follow the logic in your head and verify this is true.

If I only change the order of the statements:

```
 void f(Node node) {
      if(node == null) return;
      f(node.left);
      print node.value;
      f(node.right);
 }
```

Now it prints `4 2 5 1 3 6` -- again, follow the logic and verify it's right.

```
 void f(Node node) {
      if(node == null) return;
      f(node.left);
      f(node.right);
      print node.value;
 }
```

... prints `4 5 2 6 3 1` -- which *may* be what you want.

You may want a breadth first traversal, and you may wish to reverse the order of the output - there are examples in Google.

In a filesystem there are more children than just left and right, so it would be more like:

```
 void recursiveList(File f) { // f could be a file or a directory
      if(f is a file) {
           output file info about f
           return
      }
      // else it's a directory
      for(File entry : f.getChildren()) {
          recursiveList(entry);
      }
      output directory info about f
  }
```

Comment: which is exactly what i want, so depth-first tree recursion it is! :)

Comment: damn good answer i will write the code in java and share it tomorrow here. Thank you for your time and knowledge slim :)

Comment: But how do i know which node is left and which one right in my file-system? 
compare alphabetical? take listFiles() order?

Comment: I added something about that.

Comment: @malle this is _exactly_ what the methods I linked in my commend do.

Comment: could you give a short example boris?

Answer (score 0):

You can process, for each directory, first the subdirectories and then the files on the directory.

```
private void listDir(File dir) {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { // Directories
            if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                System.out.print(" (Directory)\n");
                listDir(files[i]); //Recursion
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { // Files
            if (!files[i].isDirectory()) {
                System.out.print(" (File)\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you want something like this:

```
private int countFiles(File dir) {
    int res = 0;
    if (files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { // Files
            if (!files[i].isDirectory()) {
                System.out.print(" (File)\n");
                res++;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
private int countFilesDeep(File dir) {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    int res = 0;
    if (files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { // Directories
            if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                System.out.print(" (Directory)\n");
                res += countFilesDeep(files[i]); //Recursion
            }
        }
    }
    res += countFiles(dir);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i wrote this:

```
 public void walkFilesystem(File f)
{

    File[] arr= f.listFiles();
    if(arr.length>0) //-> against nullPointer
    {
        for(File file : arr)
        {
            if(file.isDirectory())
            {
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath()+" (Directory)");
                walkFilesystem(file);
            }
            else if(file.isFile()&&file.getPath().contains("txt"))
            {
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath()+" (node)");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

That should work shouldn't it?

Comment: This isn't an answer. Nevertheless, the best way to find out if it works is to run it.

Comment: This will throw a nullPointerException if you pass it a directory, since arr will be null. You only want to call listFiles() if you know the file is a directory.

Comment: hmm it does not throw a null pointer... i mean i catch it with that or not: if(arr.length>0)?

Comment: I see why it works: you never pass it a non-directory. if(arr.length > 0) will throw NPE because it would try to evaluate `null.length`

Comment: If you've tested it with every input scenario you want it to work with, and it produces the output you want, then it works.

Comment: in deed i did, but i marked it as dangerous as well, thank you and have a great weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use java 8 lambda features like this

```
try (Stream<Path> walkStream = Files.walk(Paths.get("your search directory"))) {
    walkStream.forEach(f -> {
        if (f.isFile()) {
            System.out.println(f.toString() + " is file!");
        }
        //etc...
    });
}
```